# My reboot sign rotates back and forth, but I only need to go there, how to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, css

I have sign of reloading, but it go back and forth, but I need only to go back. I tried everything I know, but it doesn`t work. Please, help me, thanks:)

```js
var sign_reload = document.getElementById("reload");

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
  if (sign_reload.style.transform == "rotate(360deg)")
    sign_reload.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  else sign_reload.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
};
```

```css
#reload {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8f82e7a054.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="reload"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i></div>

    <button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the use of animation by adding a class that you remove on animation end:

```js
var sign_reload = document.getElementById("reload");

sign_reload.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  sign_reload.classList.remove('rotate');
});

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  sign_reload.classList.add('rotate');
};
```

```css
#reload {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.rotate {
  animation: change 2s;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8f82e7a054.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="reload"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i></div>

<button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```